# error LNK2005: _exit already defined in msvcrt.lib(MSVCR90.dll)_LIBCMTD.lib?

Tags: visual-c++, linker, compiler-errors, dev-c++

Hi i am using libjpeg lib and libpng lib in my application...
when i compile my application in debug mode..it is working fine...
But  when I compile my application in release mode i am getting following link error...

> ```
>  Error    41  error LNK2005: "private: __thiscall type_info::type_info(class type_info const &)" (??0type_info@@AAE@ABV0@@Z) already defined in MSVCRT.lib(ti_inst.obj)   F:\Work Projects\SnackCards XAML\SimpleGame\SimpleGame\LIBCMT.lib(typinfo.obj)  SimpleGame
> ```
>
> Error   43  error LNK2005: "private: class type_info & __thiscall type_info::operator=(class type_info const &)" (??4type_info@@AAEAAV0@ABV0@@Z) already defined in MSVCRT.lib(ti_inst.obj) F:\Work Projects\SnackCards

anybody have suggestion about this error?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You are likely using different C runtimes in the libraries and your application. Check the project settings. Libcmt is the staticically linked multi-threaded run-time, while msvcrt is the dynamically linked version.

Check that the settings match in your project properties under

```
C/C++->Code Generation->Runtime Library
```